# How to run query or read row from npr file

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

All the db issue is totally new for me.

I have some npr file ( access db file ) that i need to do some query and get some row from.
I really don't have any idea how to do it ( i never ever work with npr before ) 
someone can help me on this ?

thanks

Comment: Seems like npr is nothing but extension used to misguide. Try opening it in msaccess

Comment: OK , but i want to run SQL query on it - is it possible do do it on the msaccess that you suggested ?

Comment: Yeah it is possible... Check http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/run-a-query-HA010077157.aspx for checking out Run a query - Access

Comment: Not good - because i want to access to the file - and not to the access application.